# How do I import data from a .csv file into R without repeating the values of the first column into all the other ones?

Tags: r, csv, matrix, vector

I want to import data into R from a .csv file.

So far I have done the following:

```
> #Clear environment
rm(list=ls())

#Read my data into R
myData <- read.csv("C:/Users/.../flow.csv", header=TRUE)

#Convert from list to array
myData <- array(as.numeric(unlist(myData)), dim=c(264,3))

#Create vectors with specific values of interest: qMax, qMin
qMax <- myData[,2]
qMin <- myData[,3]

#Transform  vectors into matrices
qMax <- matrix(qMax,nrow = 12, ncol = round((length(qMax)/12)))
qMin <- matrix(qMin,nrow = 12, ncol = round((length(qMin)/12)))
```

After importing the data using `read.csv`, I have a list. I then proceed to transform this list into an array with 264 lines of data spread through 3 columns. **Here I have my first problem**.

I know that each column of my list brings a different set of data; the values are not the same. However, after I check to see what I imported, it seems that only the first column is imported correctly, but then it repeats itself for columns one and two.

Here's an image for better explanation:

[image: Matrix with the right layout, yet wrong data. Columns 2 and 3 should have different values from each other and from column 1]

The matrix has the right layout, yet wrong data. Columns 2 and 3 should have different values from each other and from column 1.

How do I correct that? I have checked the source and the original document has all the correct values.

Also, assuming I will eventually get rid of this mistake, will the proceeding lines of code from the block "#Transform  vectors into matrices" deliver a 12 x 22 matrix? The first six elements of both qMax and qMin are NA and I wish to keep it this way in the matrix. Will R perform that with these lines of code or will I need to change it?

Thank you.

---

Edit: As suggested by akrun, here's the results for `str(myData` and for `dput(droplevels(head(myData)))`

[image]

Comment: Could you please check the `str(myData)`  If possible show a small  reproducible example using `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(myData)))` and update in your post for others to understand the problem better

Comment: Import using `read.csv` creates a data frame, not a list (although you can `unlist` it).

Comment: Your data i.e. `myData` is already a `matrix`.  I meant the `dput` of the original object i.e. `myData <- read.csv(....)`  BTW `data.frame` is a `list` with columns of equal length and additional attributes.  It could be that the length of `unlist(myData)` would be 264. So by using `264, 3` as dim will repeat the same elements in the other columns.  Please check the `dim` of the original data i.e. `dim(myData)` before the `array` step